# PHP - usando isset e GETs

Tags: php

Boas gente,

Eu tenho estes 4 Gets para recolher, os mesmos saem de outra pagina.
O que pretendo é...

```
"Se apanhar($_GET) order, preço, comprador" {

    mostra valores do $_GET...

} else {

    erro.
}
```

Como faço isso?
Será assim?

```
if(isset($_GET['order'] || isset($_GET['preco'] || isset($_GET['comprador']) {
```

ou assim

```
if(isset($_GET['order'] AND isset($_GET['preco'] AND isset($_GET['comprador']) {
```

Comment: Precisa de todos válidos ou um só?

Comment: preciso de todos validos

Answer (score 3):

O [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) não é uma função é um construct language, ele possui uma diferencial que é passar N argumentos de entrada. Dessa forma a validação é feita em todos os argumentos se um deles não for válido `isset()` retorna false. É o equivalente a conectar N condição com o operador E lógico (`&&`)

Pode deixar seu código:

```
if(isset($_GET['order'], $_GET['preco'], $_GET['comprador'])){
   echo 'válido';
}else{
   echo 'inválido';
}
```

O código abaixo é equivalmente ao primeiro.

```
if(isset($_GET['order']) && isset($_GET['preco']) && isset($_GET['comprador'])){
```

Comment: Perfeito! Acho que só para usuários iniciantes seria legal dizer algo como isso *"`isset(..,..,..)` equivalete a isto `isset(...) && isset(...) && isset(...)`"*, mas já deixo o +1

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria...

```
if( isset($_GET['order']) && isset($_GET['preco']) && isset($_GET['comprador']) )
  echo 'os 3 existem';
else 
  echo 'os 3 não existem';
```

Pode trocar o `&&` por `AND` sem problemas.

Comment: Ok, fico muito agradecido pela ajuda. :D Obrigado...

Answer (score 0):

Há uma outra forma também, é utilizar o `array_diff` que vai verificar exatamente os campos

```
<?php

$obrigatorios = ["order", "preco", "comprador"];

if (!array_diff($obrigatorios, array_keys($_GET))) {
    echo "mostra valores do GET...";
} else {
    echo "Erro";
}
```

Ou você pode utilizar `array_diff_assoc`

```
<?php

$obrigatorios = ["order", "preco", "comprador"];

if( !array_diff_assoc($obrigatorios, array_keys($_GET)) ) {
    echo "mostra valores do GET...";
} else {
    echo "Erro";
}
```

https://ideone.com/JwpTh1

Comment: Qual das formas aqui apresentadas é a mais segura para passar dados?...

Comment: Todas elas tem o mesmo nível de segurança. O que pode ser testado é a performance de cada, mas mesmo assim, a diferença provavelmente é irrisória.

Comment: Na doc do php diz que o `array_diff` retorna um array, por que a validação funciona?

Comment: @Francisco Se `$_GET` possuir **exatamente** as três chaves, a função `array_diff` retornará um *array* vazio, que é um *falsy value*, isto é, considerado falso quando tratado numa operação booleana. Como foi usado o `!`, o valor passa a ser verdadeiro.

Comment: Dito isso, essa é uma limitação nesta solução que deveria estar explícita na resposta: se houver outras chaves, o código indicará erro, mesmo se os três valores desejados existirem.

Comment: @Silva é basicamente com o @AndersonCarlosWoss mencionou, mas para contornar isso você pode utilizar o `array_diff_assoc`